# CSS - Another one of those "Oops, this shouldn't be happening" questions

Tags: css, html

I've been building this site in CSS with virtually no problems, and now all in a sudden I'm experiencing a problem with some basic positioning that I can't figure out in my body-3 class div, going below my body-4 class div instead of pushing it downward and lengthening the page like normal. The page almost seems to have some sort of max length, although I don't believe I've set any sort of max page height.

```
.body-3
{
/* what's going on here?*/
```

if you query this on the testing area of the company website that I am working on right now, in the external css file, you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

This testing page is live here:

www.testing.agcomputers.net

*Note: that black box appears to be within the body-4 class div (light grey area at bottom) but they are actually contained within the .body-3 class div, and have no upper margin that should push them down into any other div.*

**I'm unable to choose an answer without enough karma, but these guys below have found my obvious mistake, where I forgot to close some divs. Thanks guys!**

Comment: By the way - You *can* accept an answer, but only after 15 minutes since asking the question. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/7586) And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 divs you did not close, which is messing with your structure:

```
<div id="transition-left">
<div id="transition-right">
<div id="center">
```

An easy way to find these problems and more is to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.testing.agcomputers.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).
Among other potential problems, you can find:

> Line 138, Column 33: **Unclosed element div.**

Comment: Ahh - The simplest things. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to close all your open divs.

You currently have 3 unclosed divs inside/including the body-3 class, which causes your body-4 div to be nested and thus not behave the way you expect it.

Comment: Don't worry about that, you'll accept when you can. Until then, go close those divs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Other people will give you a fish, I will teach you to fish for yourself.

Use XHTML (if local files, rename to .xhtml or if using PHP use the following before you send out headers (headers are sent as soon as you `echo` anything in PHP intentionally or not)...

```
  $mime = stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml');

  if ($mime) {header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');}
  else {header('Content-Type: text/html');}
```

In Firefox right click and `View Page Information` and if the `Type:` says application/xhtml+xml then it's XHTML. When you produce malformed XML (XHTML is a subset of XML) the whole page will break and you'll get an error message.

...or you could just struggle with regular HTML and *manually* validate *every single time you reload* but that wouldn't be very productive and would waste your time.

XHTML is much stricter but the best path is never the easiest. If you get stuck on *anything* because of XHTML visit me at my site, it's fully-fledged XHTML and I'll be happy to help you out.